# Searching for a phrase in proximity to another token in SOLR

Tags: solr

The following is proximity search in SOLR:

"john josh"~12

But what is I wanted to search for josh token being close not to john, but to the expression "john smith"?

Is there a way to make something like this work:

"("john smith") josh"~12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these two parsers:

1. [ComplexPhraseQueryParser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-ComplexPhraseQueryParser)
2. [XMLQueryParser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-XMLQueryParser)

I think the first one should do what you need, and maybe both can.

Comment: Thank you. ComplexPhraseQueryParser looks promising indeed. Will test if it does the job and approve the answer afterwords.

Comment: So, the following works for me (with SOLR 4.9.0): q={!complexphrase inOrder=false}content:"\\\"john smith\\\" josh"~12

Comment: The inner phrase should not be put in parentheses. If it is put in parentheses, the query will parse, but will not produce the desired result. And yes, the double quotes of the inner phrase need to be escaped with \\\