# Solr proximity search with AND and OR

Tags: solr, proximity

We would like to use this kind of query:

```
"(BMW OR AUDI) AND (Diesel OR Petrol)"~20
```

What we are trying to achieve is this result: BMW or AUDI must be 20 words away from Diesel or Petrol.

This query works fine, but without proximity:

```
(BMW OR AUDI) AND (Diesel OR Petrol)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching for a phrase in proximity to another token in SOLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49010974/searching-for-a-phrase-in-proximity-to-another-token-in-solr)